# CSS-Bug in Bootstrap-Template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

On the following template is a css bug.
If u resize your browser, you will see that the template sometimes has a horizontal scrollbar. Its not that nice for a responsive design. 
On iPhone6 (not landscape) i have the same effect. You can see the background-image on the right side.
I tryed a lot but nothing helps.
Does someone has an idea to fix it?

[Template here](http://www.bootply.com/render/129806)

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The causes of the issue are the extended headline **Sectionalize.** and col-* classes.

**Use the below code to reduce the font-size at lower screen size.**

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .v-center {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}
```

**Remove the `col-*` classes above `.container`**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Inside `id="section5"` you've got `<div class="container">` inside

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
```

Remove this and it should sort it.